# Pinterest API - pure json response?

Tags: php, json, api, pinterest

So I made a simple HTTP request to Pinterest's API to get the count of a link:

```
$this->load->library('rest');
$this->rest->initialize(array('server' => 'http://api.pinterest.com/'));
$return_data = $this->rest->get('v1/urls/count.json?callback=&url=' . $link);
```

The response I get is:

```
receiveCount({"count": 5743, "url": "http://google.com"})
```

You can [try this yourself here](http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?url=http://google.com).

I don't want the callback and I tried setting `callback=` but the parenthesis are still present so I can't parse it via `json_decode`.

Is there a better way of getting a pure json response without having to string replace the parenthesis myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Pintrest API is currently in development and is not ready for public use; they removed their own documentation a while ago. There is however a cache on [Bolt](http://tijn.bo.lt/pinterest-api) for v2 of the API.

For now I would just do a regex on the response such as

```
$return_data = preg_replace('/^receiveCount\((.*)\)$/', "\\1", $return_data);
```

And then `json_decode` that.

Comment: Thanks for this Matt, I didn't even check if their API was in development mode or not. I'll stick to the string replace hack!