# Pinterest api returns null when it's called by wp_remote_get

Tags: php, wordpress, pinterest

Pinterest api works fine in the browser side to show share count for a specific URL as [seen here for Google](http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.google.com).

But when I try to call it from wp_remote_get function of Wordpress, it returns null:

```
$url = "http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.google.com";
$response = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($url, 
    array ('timeout' => 30, 'sslverify' => false ) ) );
var_dump($response); // null
```

I want to underline that, this function block works fine when I try to get share counts of Google, Facebook or Twitter.

I also tried wp_remote_post, nothing changed with the response.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found an answer for this problem. The wp_remote_get function returns an array which has a body. But the wp_remote_retrieve_body function can't convert it into a string since it's in the form of a javascript callback (I guess).

When I get the body directly from the response of the first array and removed the callback function [as told here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647809/pinterest-api-pure-json-response), I got the response json.